# Can rows data can be customed to columns in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, row, aggregate-functions

I have the follow table in PostgreSQL

| foreign_key_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1700 | Joe |
| 1700 | Mark |
| 1700 | Luke |
| 1700 | Peter |
| 1700 | James |

I would like to change to

| foreign_key_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1700 | Joe;Mark;Luke;Peter,James |

How to do it? I have tried crosstab but it does not seems the right way. Any help ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by with aggregation should work:

```
SELECT foreign_key_id, string_agg(name, ';') FROM table_name GROUP BY foreign_key_id;
```